# Replace cell values by column names in SQL

Tags: mysql

We have a table in Mysql version 8.0.22, given as `table`

```
description| amount | construction | cleaning | furniture | electronics |other
-----------  ------  -------------  ----------  ---------   -----------   -----

cleaning day|  5    |    0         |   1      |      0    |    0      |  0

Electronics |   4   |      0       |   0      |      0     |    1        |  0
```

The goal is to get following output;

```
description| amount| category
-----------------------------
 cleaning day| 5  | cleaning
  Electronics|  4 | electronics
```

As seen, we have one column `category` now. Here is my attempt it;

```
SELECT *,
IF(construction=1,'construction',IF(cleaning=1,'cleaning',IF(electronics=1,
'electronics', IF(furniture=1,'furniture',IF(other=1,'other'))))) AS 'Category'

FROM table;
```

But unfortunately, it gives me following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) in the pre-written template: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check    the manual 
  that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))))) AS 'Category'

FROM table;

END' at line 14
```

Can I please get some help with this error? Help is appreciated.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE` here with `IF`:

```
SELECT *,
    COALESCE(IF(construction = 1, 'construction', NULL),
             IF(cleaning = 1, 'cleaning', NULL),
             IF(furniture = 1, 'furniture', NULL),
             IF(electronics = 1, 'electronics', NULL),
             IF(other = 1, 'other', NULL)) AS category
FROM yourTable;
```

That being said, a much better table design would be to just maintain a single column with the category value.  This design also scales better because adding new category values does not require adding new columns, which is another drawback to your current approach.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I agree it is not a very efficient design. Actually it is a challenge, I am practicing on Codesignal to improve my data manipulation skills, slicing and dicing tables.